# What kind of exception can a selenium method throw?

Tags: selenium

I just started with selenium and wanted to know the kind of exception a selenium function can throw like say WaitForFramToLoad().

Basically, it will help m a lot if some one can point to a link which lists the general exceptions a selenium method can throw, so that I can catch the expected exceptions and throw the unwanted ones.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which client language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Two years late, but here's a link to some common exceptions: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html

In my experience the most common exception i came across was `ElementNotFound`

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the Selenium 1.0 api's throw `Selenium.SeleniumException` exclusively.